# How to implement a singleThreadedScheduledExcecutor in wildfly

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, concurrency, wildfly

I have need of a single threaded scheduled executor service in application code that is to run on both wildfly and SE. The java concurrency library provides a singleThreadedScheduledExecutorService. The problem with wildfly is that managed-scheduled-executor-service does not allow maxThreads to be specified.I thought I could create a class that referenced a managed-scheduled-executor-service and a managed-executor-service with a maxThreads of one. Then have the schedule operation submit the job to the managed-executor-service. There is a problem with the generics on callables that causes the error

```
 incompatible types: inference variable V has incompatible bounds
 equality constraints: J
 lower bounds: java.util.concurrent.Future<T>
```

to Occur.

My code follows. The pattern works for runnables which do not return anything, but fails on callables. The method  "public  ScheduledFuture schedule(Callable job, long delay, TimeUnit unit)" is the problematic one. Is there anyway to work around this?

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ExecutorImpl implements RITExecutor {
 private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName());

 @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/singleThreaded")
 private  ScheduledExecutorService TIMER;
 @Resource (lookup = "java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default")
 private ExecutorService EXECUTOR;

 @Override
 public <J> ScheduledFuture<J> schedule(Callable<J> job, long delay, TimeUnit unit) {
    return TIMER.schedule(()->EXECUTOR.submit(job),delay,unit);
 }
 @Override
 public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable job, long delay, TimeUnit unit) {
    return TIMER.schedule(()->EXECUTOR.submit(job),delay,unit);
 }
 @Override
 public <J> Future<J> submit(Callable<J> job) {
    return EXECUTOR.submit(job);
 }
 @Override
 public Future<?> submit(Runnable job) {
    return EXECUTOR.submit(job);
 }
 @Override
 public <J> Future<J> submit(Runnable job, J result) {
    return EXECUTOR.submit(job, result);
 }
```

Comment: and where is the text which causes the error? Does it compile on JavaSE?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by compile on java SE, the class did not compile with the javac compiler. There is another implementation of the class that is injected in the java SE environment which used Executors to alloccate a singleThreadedScheduledExecutor so there was no need call one executor service from another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with a cast. Don't know why I didn't think of that sooner.

```
  @Override
    public <J> ScheduledFuture<J> schedule(Callable<J> job, long delay, TimeUnit unit) {
        return (ScheduledFuture<J>)TIMER.schedule(()->EXECUTOR.submit(job),delay,unit);
```